# How to make another window which has the same geometry (position and width, height) as the original window, to simulate that the entire page changed?

Tags: python, pyqt5

In my program , I need to chnage the entire layout of the Login page to the register page. After I googled some possible ways to do this, I understood that I have to close the login window and open a new one with the register layout. The problem that I found just how to open a new window, but not to open it in the same place on the screen and with the same dimensions (if the windows was resized)! I tried this, thinking this would be the proper way ( the minimal example I modified is from an older SO question:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget

class UIWindow(object):
    def setupUI(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setGeometry(250, 250, 300, 400)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("UIWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.ToolsBTN = QPushButton('text', self.centralwidget)
        self.ToolsBTN.move(50, 350)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


class UIToolTab(object):
    def setupUI(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setGeometry(250, 250, 300, 400)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("UIToolTab")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.CPSBTN = QPushButton("text2", self.centralwidget)
        self.CPSBTN.move(100, 350)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    qr = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.uiWindow = UIWindow()
        self.uiToolTab = UIToolTab()
        self.startUIWindow()

    def startUIToolTab(self):
        geo = self.frameGeometry()
        left, top, width, height = geo.left(), geo.top(), geo.width(), geo.height()
        self.uiToolTab.setupUI(self)
        self.setGeometry(left, top, width, height)
        self.uiToolTab.CPSBTN.clicked.connect(self.startUIWindow)
        self.show()

    def startUIWindow(self):
        geo = self.frameGeometry()
        left, top, width, height = geo.left(), geo.top(), geo.width(), geo.height()
        self.uiWindow.setupUI(self)
        self.setGeometry(left, top, width, height)
        self.uiWindow.ToolsBTN.clicked.connect(self.startUIToolTab)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This keeps the new window in about the same area of the screen, but it's geometry somehow changes! Is this an issue with my screen maybe? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The most appropriate solution is to use QStackedWidget

Comment: Okay closing one window and opening another is one way but it is not the only nor per-sae even the best way -- depending on what you are doing a stackable widget might be more efficient or swapping classes.  However since this question has been pointed to another possible answer nothing can now be done here.  Check my profile and shoot me a pm if you want more help with this and/or perhaps getting an understanding of all the possible solutions rather than just take this as the only way.

Comment: Actually I disagree @eyllanesc using a QStackedWidget is but one answer and may not be the best solution -- for instance if they are using QMainWindow and the Login window is contained within the Central Widget simply swapping out what is contained within that Central Widget would be the best answer -- then again depending on what they are doing creating that secondary window might be the best solution.  Each method has its pros/cons and it all boils down to what they are doing specifically to know which one best solves their issues

Comment: @eyllanes okay but do they really need to hold onto that Login Window going forward and/or do they really want to hold on to that Registration Window after their done using it -- basically again it depends on the actual usage as to what the best solution would be -- yes if they are going to perhaps need that login/register/whatever over and over again holding onto to it within memory makes sense -- however if its just going to get used only once then holding onto it within a stackable widget makes absolutely no sense